# How toggle visibility of SSRS subreport header?

Tags: reporting-services, show-hide, subreport

My SQL Server Reporting Services main report's Details row has a subreport in a textbox.  When the main report runs, the Details row may return many lines of data, each such line containing a corresponding version of the subreport.  The subreport has a single group which toggles visibility of the subreport's Details row.  This is all working fine.  The problem is that the subreport has a text header that appears in every one of the main report's Details rows, which is very distracting.  How can I hide the subreport's text header and show it only if the subreport's group row is toggled to expose the subreport's details?

Comment: Can't you just use the same expression to hide the header row?  You can set the row visibility without using a group.  If it's more complex than that, I can put together more details, but I would require a look at the design view of the subreport and possibly a view of the current result.

Comment: Steve: Thanks for your comment.  I'm beginning to think that what I'm seeing is SSRS' intended design behaviour for subreports.  A workaround I'm currently testing is to toggle the subreport via a textbox on the same row, such that the user sees only one subreport (with text header row & multiple detail rows) at a time.  That's not perfect, but it may do.  Another option, I think, is to just remove the subreport's text header.  Most (but not all) users will understand the data in context without the text headers, but it's better to retain them.